# Directus CMS not updating content

Tags: content-management-system, directus

my company has used directus CMS for a while and right now, our content that we update through the app is not updating on our site. Whether it is adding or removing content, it is not working. It is also not sending an email notification when a file has been changed or added, as it usually does. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is a bit vague — perhaps you could share more info on your setup, logs/errors regarding your issue, etc?

Comment: @RANGER I can't give too many details. I don't see any logs/errors. I haven't worked with this for too long, and this CMS well predates my time with the company. This is for an Angular/Progress application. 1 table does not update no matter what the changes, while others do. I don't know where the logs are stored. I am a Jr front-end developer who was told "this is broken, fix it". Where do you suggest I start?

Comment: @RANGER I found the logs. 'Update Failed: Invalid group code of [CS5GT, CS5UT, DAT3S, DAT3L, DAT3X, DSTPR, STMX, DENMAX]'. What does this mean?